# Laravel Sanctum | ReactJS | SPA Auth Issue

Tags: php, reactjs, single-page-application, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum for SPA authentication. My SPA is react and resides in same repo as of Laravel. It means that i am using Laravel React UI scaffolding.

My **First** concern is that while visiting login page of my SPA app, i see `XSRF-TOKEN` and `app_session` cookie without sending request to `sanctum/csrf-cookie`

[image]

> Question: Why cookies are getting generated without calling csrf-cookie endpoint?

Can it be that Laravel generates it by default?

**Secondly**, calls to login and csrf-cookie are working fine but `/user` API is failing

[image]

My Environment file `.env` has below conf:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
# localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='app.vm.com'
SESSION_DOMAIN='vm.com'
```

`sanctum.php` has below conf:

```
return [

'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1')),

'expiration' => null,

'middleware' => [
    'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
],

'prefix' => 'api',
'guard' => 'api',
];
```

`cors.php` has below conf:

```
return [

'paths' => ['api/*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

`kernel.php` has also required changes:

```
'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
 ],
```

My routes `web.php` looks like as:

```
$spa = function () {
    return view('app');
};
Route::get('/{view?}', $spa)->where('view', '(.*)')->name('catchall');
```

`api.php` route file looks like as below:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
  });
});

Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login');
Route::post('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');
```

Please assist in solving assisting 401 error for `/user` end point. I have followed many tutorials but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

adding correct SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS domain with a port number should fix the issue.

In my case, my laravel instance is running at 127.0.0.1:8001 and add this to .env solved my problem